# How can I access google api script on the window object in next.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, next.js, react-helmet

I am trying to use google api with a next.js app. I was reading the documentation and the next.js recommendation for implementing google api is to use next.js Head component. I loaded the script but can't seem to access the gapi property...

```js
export default () => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script
        src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init"
        async
        defer
      ></script>
    </Head>
    <Login />
  </div>
);
```

My GoogleClient file starts with

```js
const GoogleClient = ({api}) => {
...
}
```

I used a Login component that initializes the GoogleClient file as

```js
const Login = () => {
    useEffect(()=> {
        GoogleClient(window.gapi)
    }, [])
...
}
```

When I console.log window the gapi property exists on the window object but when I call window.gapi I get the following error
--> Property 'gapi' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
I googled the error but haven't seen any posts on how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this was a duplicate error to other posts. I needed to install `@types/gapi` or `@types/gapi.auth2` packages.

If you install the later, you would not need the former.

```
npm install @types/gapi.auth2 -D
```